# Making a Continuous Floor (Actionscript 3)

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm making a game similar to 'Run' (http://www.albinoblacksheep.com/games/run) but I can't quite figure out the floor part. I'm not wanting the sides and a ceiling like in 'Run', just the main floor.

I'm new to Flash game development (AS3) but I know the basics. I realise the character isn't moving and is just turning (the level itself moves). How do a make a continuous floor, do I have to make a very long .fla file, or do I have to do this with code?

All ideas and help appreciated, Thanks. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Tiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tile-based_game). Basically, a tile game consists of a lot of squared tiles, which are inserted when appear in screen and removed when goes out.
In your case, maybe you could use a big tile, with screen's size.

You can visualize a good example [here](http://www.tonypa.pri.ee/tbw/tut13.html), also a very good resource for gamedev on Flash.

Comment: I'd like to get a more from behind view though, similar to the 'Run' game. With Tiles it seems to be an over head view only.

Comment: It's basically the same concept. Things are comming and going out the screen, and the player is "mapped" to some of these tiles - the holes are like empty spaces in the tilemap. Sure you'll need render that graphics using 3D features.

As you said, if you're new to Flash gamedev, you should start with a simpler game first.

Comment: Or if you think this hard, you could try Unity3D, and make a real 3D game, easier than doing it with Flash.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate sprites of the edge of the screen and either recycle them when their x < some value or dispose and create new ones.

Comment: Could you explain a little more?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use Bitmap.draw() to draw different pixels on a Bitmap that you've applied a 3D transformation to. You can see the basic concept illustrated [here](http://flexdiary.blogspot.com/2012/06/endless-scrolling-bathroom.html).